# Popup for google extension isn't loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

My popup won't load, links to the GitHub, file structure manafest.json, etc

GitHub: https://github.com/Bluedog76/Kahoot-AntiCheat

manifest.json: I'm not sure if it is due to me trying to start using native messaging. Im also not %100 if the directories were right

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Kahoot Anti Cheat",
    "description": "Kahoot Anti Cheat made to stop people not play, inaportiate names, and more",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "storage",
      "activeTab",
      "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "scripts/popup/popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
      "128": "images/128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
        "matches": [
          "https://play.kahoot.it/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

content.js: this is justing send all the Items to the chrome extension, I was just using it to start getting the spans of the names

```
//This is a content script running indavidualy on play.kahot.it


//Messaging and reciving from and to host to display on wepage
while (true) {
    let itemId = document.querySelectorAll(':not([id])');
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "idSend"});
    port.postMessage({item: itemId});
    //port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      //if (msg.question === "Who's there?")
        //port.postMessage({answer: "Madame"});
      //else if (msg.question === "Madame who?")
        //port.postMessage({answer: "Madame... Bovary"});
    //};
}
```

popup.html : there is some extra clutter from using chromes storage API because I was new to using it

```
<!Doctype html>
<body style="width:580px; height:600px"></body>
<html>
    <body>
        <title>Settings</title>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">  
            <p>Settings</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box" value="Type here to save"/><br/>
            <input type="button" id="save" value="Save"/><br/>
            <input type="button" id="load" value="Load"/><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="switch3"/>Enable AntiCheat<br/>
            Saved item: <div id="savedList"></div>
        </div>

        Saved item: <div id="savedList2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
```

popup.js The faction to save and load are apart of the clutter from before

```
function save() {
    var newItem = document.getElementById("box").value;
    localStorage.box = newItem;
}
function load() {
    var savedDiv = document.getElementById("savedList")
    savedDiv.innerHTML = localStorage.box;
    
}

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save);
document.getElementById("load").addEventListener("click", load);


//Send and recive to the content script (Host)
while (true) {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
        console.assert(port.name === "idSend");
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
            var savedDiv2 = document.getElementById("savedList2")
            savedDiv2.innerHTML = msg.item;
        });
      });
}
```

popup.css

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
#wrap {
    height: 600;
    width: 600;
}
```

[image]

It was meant to load but the popup is not loading, thank youm

Comment: Move </html> to the end.

Comment: Open the task manager and you'll see your extension hanged consuming 100% CPU. Kill the process and remove `while (true)` in your code.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you, I will change it out to be more CPU friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the CPU usage in my extension. It wasn't loading due to me coding on a GitHub VM and executing on my Chrome book, which couldn't handle the usage. The answer was solved by @wOxxOm.
Basicly just change out the
`While (true) { }`

Answer (score 0):

In popup.html, your closing `html` tag wasn't wrapping the script & link to popup.js and popup.css.

```
<!Doctype html>

<body style="width:580px; height:600px"></body>
<html>

  <body>
    <title>Settings</title>
    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
      <p>Settings</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="text" id="box" value="Type here to save" /><br />
      <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" /><br />
      <input type="button" id="load" value="Load" /><br />
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" value="switch3" />Enable AntiCheat<br />
      Saved item: <div id="savedList"></div>
    </div>

    Saved item: <div id="savedList2"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">

</html>
```

Comment: I did this and the extension still isn't working. I can load it fine but when I go to click on the extension, the popup.html window does not appear. If I cannot find an answer, I'm just gonna recode it or scrap it.